# python selenium webdriver getting httpStatusCode 503 when logging in to website

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on a personal project to scrape my personal transactions off of my bank website to build some analytics off it. 
I am using python with selenium web driver. 
I can almost login to the my bank site, but right when the form gets submitted i am getting error in chrome console
(I was earlier getting CORS errors, but they are circumvented by using --disable-web-security option)

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity)
```

I am pretty sure, the real reason is something else, I can login to the bank site without using selenium webdriver - without issues.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time 

opts = Options()
opts.headless = False
opts.add_argument("test-type")
opts.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
opts.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")

# assert opts.headless  # Operating in headless mode
browser = Chrome(options=opts)

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

browser.get('https://authentication.td.com/uap-ui/index.html?consumer=easyweb&locale=en_CA#/login/easyweb-getting-started/')
user_name_field = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "username")))
password_field = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "password")))
user_name_field.send_keys('my-card-number')
password_field.send_keys('my-password')
password_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
print('submission done')
print(browser.current_url)
banking_hr_field_results = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(), 'TD ALL-INCLUSIVE')]")))
print(browser.current_url)

browser.close()
quit()
```

Comment: Would you even *want* this to work? You are talking about your real bank account here?

Comment: check the bank policy, it's not allowed to perform in most of the cases. If you really need this to be done, check if any API is available.

Comment: no api available.. i checked.. i must be missing some request headers.. will check.. this should work. i tried the same code against another utility company and it works fine with them..

Comment: Hi, robin bajaj. Did you solve your problem and can you login using selenium web browser?

Comment: nah man.. i wish i could.. i think they are blocking it from their side..